Android DatePicker fragment - "null object reference" error in logcat
I'm attempting to add a DatePicker to my android app following the documentation provided by google here. I'm trying to make it so the picker appears when a button is pushed, allowing the user to input a calendar date. I've gotten most of the way through it, however whenever my app tries to load in the button it crashes with an error reading:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.getDecorView()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.initializeViewTreeOwners(ComponentActivity.java:474)
                                                                                                        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.setContentView(ComponentActivity.java:438)
                                                                                                        at com.example.assignmentNotifier.ui.assignment.AssignmentEntryScreenKt.AssignmentInputForm(AssignmentEntryScreen.kt:152)
                                                                                                        at com.example.assignmentNotifier.ui.assignment.AssignmentEntryScreenKt.AssignmentEntryBody(AssignmentEntryScreen.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at com.example.assignmentNotifier.ui.assignment.AssignmentEntryScreenKt$AssignmentEntryScreen$2.invoke(AssignmentEntryScreen.kt:72)
                                                                                                        at com.example.assignmentNotifier.ui.assignment.AssignmentEntryScreenKt$AssignmentEntryScreen$2.invoke(AssignmentEntryScreen.kt:71)

Here is the relevant code where I try to create this button in AssignmentEntryScreen.kt:
//Date Picker button.
findViewById<Button>(R.id.pickDate).setOnClickListener {
    val newFragment = DatePickerFragment()
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"datePicker")
}

The datePickerFragment.kt itself:
package com.example.assignmentNotifier


import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.app.Dialog
import android.app.DialogFragment
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.DatePicker
import com.example.assignmentNotifier.ui.assignment.AssignmentEntryDestination.setContentView
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.Locale

@Suppress("DEPRECATION", "OVERRIDE_DEPRECATION")
class DatePickerFragment : DialogFragment(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    private val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    private val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("MMM. dd, yyyy", Locale.US)

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle): Dialog {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker.
        setContentView(R.layout.datepicker)

        val year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it.
        return DatePickerDialog(activity, this, year, month, day)

    }

    override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
        calendar.set(year, month, day)
        returnFormattedDate(calendar.timeInMillis)
    }

    private fun returnFormattedDate(timestamp: Long): String? {
        return formatter.format(timestamp)

    }
}

And the R.layout.datepicker.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pickDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pick date"/>
    

</LinearLayout>

My understanding is that this is some issue with how I am trying to display the button, that I'm not properly accessing the xml file it's stored in first before attempting to display it on line 153. I'm at a loss as to how this can be fixed, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

You need to inflate your XML view via onCreateView().

@LawrenceGimenez Would I do this in  AssignmentEntryScreen.kt right above where I create the button?
